# Unable to retrieve child resources - Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Storage Explorer to read data from my Azure storage emulator.

I can create Containers just fine and even use them, until I turn off my machine. When I turn mt machine on and start using the explorer again, I keep getting this error:

[image]

If I try and create a container with the same name as the ones I cant see, I get an error saying container already exists so the container still exists somewhere, just that my explorer can't retrieve it. And the container names are all in lowercase so not sure whats happening!

Comment: What’s the name of your container?

Comment: I just called it like 'newcontainer' as a test

Comment: Looks like a known issue with Azure Storage Explorer. Please see this thread: https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/6074.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check and make sure to have container name and blob names are
   between 3 and 63 characters .
2. If you are usingt proxy settings in storage explorer to connect to your account, please
   verify that proxy settings are properly formatted by checking as they can be
   case sensitive.

[image]

- If set to Use environment variablesmake sure to set HTTPS_PROXY or
  HTTP_PROXY environment variables are set as given. If these are not
  correct , then it may not connect to the server properly.
- After that restart the explorer .

Also check the similar  issue: [Unable to retrieve child resources - "The specifed resource name contains invalid characters" · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/6010)